# Cant find operator>>(std::istringstream, Eigen) although I define it

Tags: c++11, templates, containers, operator-overloading

I am trying to use an Eigen class inside a data container (`Data<T>` with `T` begin an `Eigen::Matrix<...>`). At some point, the `Data<>` class tries to call `operator>>(std::istringstream, Eigen::Matrix<...>)` which fails because that operator is not defined.

I have implement it myself, in several flavours (template based and non templated based). This are my trials:

```
std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> &t)
{
    return str;
}

template <typename T>
std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t)
{
    return str;
}

std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t)
{
    return str;
}

std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> &t)
{
    return str;
}

std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> &t)
{
    return str;
}

std::istringstream &operator>>(std::istringstream &str, Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> t)
{
    return str;
}
```

I dont want to do anything inside the operator, at least for now. Basically, what the library does is to read an xml file and build the appropiate object inside `Data<>` calling the operator>>, but I dont need that, so empty implementation.

Still, the compiler complains it can't find the operator with the following error:

```
SofaFramework/sofa/core/objectmodel/Data.h:553:10: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char>’} and ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9.3.0/sstream:38
```

I am not sure what can be wrong here. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Did you put the template versions in a headerfile or in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: header file. and the header file, afaik, is correctly included in the other files

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems with a plain overload: https://godbolt.org/z/9-VtmA and a template version works fine too: https://godbolt.org/z/S2tBJj

Comment: is std::istream the same as std::istringstream?

Comment: No, it's closer to the base class, so it'll accept input from a lot more streams than if you restrict it to `istringstream`s - but for this test, it doesn't matter. I just shortened it down because I didn't see any reason to restrict it.

Comment: Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/GhWU-G) make a difference? Or [this](https://godbolt.org/z/UG6JGQ) that includes the fixed sized matrices too.

Comment: Apparently it looks like it was an issue with ADL. I have added the operators inside Eigen namespace and it finds them perfectly. I have absolutely no clue why the version without template was not working though...

Comment: Hmm, I added all mine in the global namespace :-)

Comment: That is true... but your call is also happening in the global namespace. Mine happens in sofa::core::objectmodel namespace. Could that matter?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://godbolt.org/z/QhngiA but there's probably _some_ lookup magic going awry.

Comment: This example looks closer to what I really have. It fails like in the real case: https://godbolt.org/z/LpCq7d

Comment: Sorry for the noise. The example is working fine, just need some adjustments on the template arguments. Ill recheck what is happening in the real case https://godbolt.org/z/R8NXfT

Comment: Better take all template parameters while you're at it :-) https://godbolt.org/z/OPg3t2